# How to sort an array by date that contains WP post objects created by merging get_posts results?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I want to create a single array of posts by merging the results of 2 separate `get_posts` queries, and have the array ordered by published date.

In my code below, the get_posts for `$args_b` and `$args_a` have been merged into one array, but they are separated: The 9 titles of `$args_b` are listed first and then the 9 titles of `$args_a`.  I want them to be mixed, and ordered by date. How do I sort them?

```
<?php
    $args_a = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'category_name' => 'shinmatsudo',
    'category__in' => array( 227 ),
    'category__not_in' => array( 3 ),
    'meta_query' => array(
                          'relation' => 'AND',
                                              array(
                                                    'key'     => '1b',
                                                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                                     ),
    
                                               array(
                                                    'key'     => '1d',
                                                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                                     ),
                                                                
                          ), 
    );?>
    
    
    <?php
    $args_b = array(
    'category_name' => 'matsudo',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'category__in' => array( 329 ),
    'category__not_in' => array( 3 ),
    'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'and',
                                    array(
                                    'key'=> '2a',
                                    'value' => array('2020-02-01' , '2020-06-01'),
                                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                    'type' => 'DATE',
                                    ),
                        ),
    );
    ?>
    
    
    <?php
    global $post;
    $my_posts= array_merge( get_posts($args_b), get_posts($args_a) );
    
    
    foreach($my_posts as $post):setup_postdata($post);?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>
        
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for editting my question.  Sorry for my poor language skills.  I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merging the results of 2 separate queries won't change the order, so you will need to do a sort on them yourself.

Because because `get_posts` returns an array of objects, we need to use a sort function that lets you create a user-defined comparison (e.g. [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)) - in other words we tell it what values to sort on and in what order.

If you are using **PHP 7**, you can use an anonymous function for the sort and the ["spaceship operator" `<=>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php/31298778#31298778) to do the comparison, so this is all you need:

```
usort($my_posts, function($post_a, $post_b) {
    // Compare the post_date of the posts, and if $post_b is newer, then it will be displayed first
    return $post_b->post_date <=> $post_a->post_date;
});
```

(Note that normally you would use `return $a->value <=> $b->value;` to return the results in ascending order, but as we are working with dates and want the newest first, then we need to reverse the comparison to be `return $b->value <=> $a->value;`)

So in your code, you just need to use it like this:

```
<?php
// do your merge...
$my_posts= array_merge( get_posts($args_b), get_posts($args_a) );

// sort the resulting array...
usort($my_posts, function($post_a, $post_b) {
    return $post_b->post_date <=> $post_a->post_date;
});   

// and now process the new sorted array as required.    
foreach($my_posts as $post):setup_postdata($post);?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

---

**UPDATE**: If you are still using **PHP 5** (which you shouldn't be!), you can use the following instead:

```
usort($my_posts, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->post_date < $b->post_date)       return -1;
    elseif ($a->post_date > $b->post_date)   return 1;
    else                                     return 0;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much !  I just tried by method of PHP7.  It works completely as I expected !  Can I ask you one more thing?  I use 'paged' => $paged usually in array for pagination.  Now, where should I set it in this case?  I set it to both $args_a and $args_b, but pagination does not appear.

Comment: Glad it worked! Setting up pagination on custom queries is a bit more complicated. That's a whole new question, but here are a few related SO questions: [Custom wp_query with working pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437554/) & [paginate WP_Query results when there's an offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227520/) or this page: [Use WP_Query to Create Pagination ](https://www.wpblog.com/use-wp_query-to-create-pagination/)... However I'm not sure how you'd do pagination with what you're doing because you are sorting the results *after* the query... that's a tough one!

Comment: @FluttyKitten Thank you for your reply.  Thanks again for related links.

Comment: @FluttyKitten Its tough as you mentioned.  No result in these hours.  I give up to solve it by myself, and will make new question.